On conditional expectation of count at which event occurred
I have tried countless searches with different keywords, but without success of finding a similar question. I'm sure it exists, but meanwhile I ask this question here. This exercise is from An Intermediate Course in Probability by Gut.

Exercise 2.7 Independent repetitions of an experiment are performed. $A$ is an event that occurs with probability $p$, $0<p<1$. Let $T_k$ be the number of the performance at which $A$ occurs the $k$th time, $k=1,2,\ldots$. Compute 
(a) $E(T_3\mid T_1=5)$,
(b) $E(T_1\mid T_3=5)$.

I think the relevant distributions here are the geometric and negative binomial distributions, i.e. the number of trials until first success and the number of trials with $n$ successes respectively. It is clear I think that $T_1\in\text{Ge}(p)$, where the pmf of $T_1$ is given by $p(1-p)^{k-1}$, $k=1,2,\ldots$. Now, I am not sure about this, but I think $T_2$ and $T_3$ are $\text{NBin}(2,p)$ and $\text{NBin}(3,p)$ respectively. I also know of the fact that $\text{NBin}(n,p)$ is just a sum of $n$ independent random variables geometrically distributed with success probability $p$.
Here's a naïve attempt at solving (a). If we assume $T_3\in \text{NBin}(3,p)$, then $T_3=X_1+X_2+X_3$ where $X_i\in\text{Ge}(p)$. I would guess e.g. $X_1=T_1$ and so \begin{align}E(T_3\mid T_1=5)&=E(X_1+X_2+X_3\mid X_1=5)\\ &=E(5+X_2+X_3)\\ &=5+\frac2p.\end{align} I am not at all sure about this. Alternatively, this exercise does appear in a chapter on order statistics, and I notice that $T_1\leq T_2\leq T_3$, and if I could somehow obtain the joint pmf, then I think I'd be able to solve both (a) and (b).
Thanks for any help or hints.

Your $5+\frac 2p$ looks correct for (a), and linearity of expectation as you seem to have used is a good way to do it.

The joint pmf is $P(T_1=t_1,T_2=t_2,T_3=t_3) $ $= P(X_1=t_1-0,X_2=t_2-t_1,X_3=t_3-t_2) $ $=p(1-p)^{t_1-0-1} \mathbf{I}{[0<t_1]}p(1-p)^{t_2-t_1-1} \mathbf{I}{[t_1<t_2]}p(1-p)^{t_3-t_2-1} \mathbf{I}{[t_2<t_3]} $ $= p^3(1-p)^{t_3-3} \mathbf{I}{[0<t_1<t_2<t_3]}$

For (a), see above.
For (b), put $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ and notice that $E[X_1\mid S_n=x]=\frac{x}{n}$ if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are identically distributed. To prove this, we need the claim that $E[X_i\mid S_n]=E[X_j\mid S_n]$. We use the definition of conditional expectation to prove this. Simply observe that $$E[E[X_i\mid S_n]\cdot 1_H] = E[X_i\cdot 1_H] = E[X_j\cdot 1_H],$$ for any $H\in\sigma(S_n)$ and $E[X_i\mid S_n]$ is $\sigma(S_n)$-measurable. Since $E[X_i\mid S_n]$ satisfies the definition of what it means to be $E[X_j\mid S_n]$, we see that the two are equal in the sense that one can be chosen to represent the other or vice versa. Next, by linearity of conditional expectation $$\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i\mid S_n]=E[S_n|S_n]=S_n$$ and the claim gives $nE[X_1\mid S_n]=S_n$, which shows that $E[X_1\mid S_n=x]=\frac{x}{n}$. (b) now follows from noting that $$E[T_1\mid T_3=5]=E[X_1\mid X_1+X_2+X_3=5]=\frac53.$$
